# Cannot install Cocoapods, keep getting error

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I have been trying to install cocoapods but I keep getting an error. I have tried the following commands and get the same result.

```
sudo gem install cocoapods    
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
    current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.13.1/ext/ffi_c
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20200726-37338-rvqxhv.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

You might have to install separate package for the ruby development
environment, ruby-dev or ruby-devel for example.

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.13.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-19/2.6.0/ffi-1.13.1/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot of searching I finally came across a solution that I believe works. If you are use Mac OS Catalina you need to use Brew.

1. Open Terminal on your Mac.
2. Now, run

   ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" < /dev/null 2> /dev/null
3. Install cocoapods using brew

   brew install cocoapods

cocoapods is ready to use now!

Comment: If you already have installed Homebrew you can skip step 2.